# Pandas extract substring from column of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframes

```
df1:
Name
0   AAa
1   BBB
2   ccc

df2:
Description
0   text AAa clinic text
1   text bbb hospital text
```

I want to add another column to df2 that extracts Name from Description, but the Name has to be followed by either 'clinic' or 'hospital'. So if Description is "text AAa text", I don't want AAa to be extracted

I feel like this should be straightforward but for some reason I am stuck and can't find a solution

I have tried the following but it returns df2['Extracted Name'] all None

```
def df_matcher(x):
    for i in df1['Name']:
        if ((i.lower() + " clinic" in x.lower()) or (i.lower() + " hospital" in x.lower())):
            return i

df2['Extracted Name'] = df2['Description'].apply(df_matcher)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `str.extract` with a regex pattern:

```
pat = r'(?i)\b(%s)\s(?:clinic|hospital)' % '|'.join(df1.Name)
df2['col'] = df2['Description'].str.extract(pat)
```

---

```
              Description  col
0    text AAa clinic text  AAa
1  text bbb hospital text  bbb
```

Comment: I have tried your answer and it generates "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 35, placement implies 1"
Any idea as to why this could happen? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try escaping the names in `df1.Name` column: `import re; pat = r'(?i)\b(%s)\s(?:clinic|hospital)' % '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1.Name))`

Comment: It fixes the error but for some reason df2['col'] is all NaN. I don't have much experience with regex, so if you could explain what this regex should do, maybe I could find out why it isn't extracting what we want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

If the part you want to remove appears exactly before clinic or hospital, you don't need the first `dataframe` and you can try this:

```
df2['split'] = df2.Description.str.split()
df2['index'] = df2['split'].apply(lambda x:x.index('clinic') if 'clinic' in x else x.index('hospital'))

df2['remove'] = df2.apply(lambda x:x['spilit'][x['index'] - 1], axis=1)
df2['Extracted Name'] = df2.apply(lambda x:x['Description'].replace(x['remove'], ''), axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried your answer and it generates this error "ValueError: 'hospital' is not in list" 
Correct me if I am wrong, but I think your answer assumes that a) df2.Description will always contain clinic/ hospital which is not the case
b) String we want to extract will always be one word, but that's not the case also, that's why I think we need to use df1.Name